# How to setup rounding halves to down in f-string format?

Tags: python, decimal, rounding

I'm trying to change the behaviour of my code in this way, expected behaviour:

```
2249 -> 2.2
2250 -> 2.2
2251 -> 2.3
2349 -> 2.3
2350 -> 2.3
2351 -> 2.4
```

But `f'{num:.3g}'` rounds it differently:

```
from decimal import *
def format_number(num):
  getcontext().prec = 1
  getcontext().rounding = ROUND_HALF_DOWN

  num = Decimal(num)
  print(num)
  num = float(f'{num:.3g}')
  print(num)
  magnitude = 0
  while abs(num) >= 1000:
    magnitude += 1
    num /= 1000.
  num = round(num * 10.) / 10.
  return f"{f'{num:f}'.rstrip('0').rstrip('.')}{['', 'k', 'M', 'B', 'T'][magnitude]}"

format_number(2349)
2349
2350.0
'2.4k'
```

How can I change it and keep "thouthands to letter" replacement?

Comment: Is the part at the top your expected behaviour or your current behaviour

Comment: It is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the precision width of your format of num as 2 instead of 3. that will round the digits after the precision width. since you only seem to want precision of the first two digits it will round these using the remaining digits.

```py
from decimal import *


def format_number(num):
    getcontext().prec = 1
    getcontext().rounding = ROUND_HALF_DOWN

    num = Decimal(num)
    #print(num)
    num = float(f'{num:.2g}')
    #print(num)
    magnitude = 0
    while abs(num) >= 1000:
        magnitude += 1
        num /= 1000.
    num = round(num * 10.) / 10.
    return f"{f'{num:f}'.rstrip('0').rstrip('.')}{['', 'k', 'M', 'B', 'T'][magnitude]}"


nums = [2249, 2250, 2251, 2349, 2350, 2351, 2349345, 2351345]
for num in nums:
    print(f"{num} -> {format_number(num)}")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2249 -> 2.2k
2250 -> 2.2k
2251 -> 2.3k
2349 -> 2.3k
2350 -> 2.3k
2351 -> 2.4k
2349345 -> 2.3M
2351345 -> 2.4M
```

Comment: Thank you. But this code also rounds 155 -> 150, 184 -> 180. This should not happen.

Comment: so whats the rouding rules?

Comment: Rules: don't change less than 1000. I added `if num > 999: your code else return num`.

Comment: I think he wants the trailing 50 to be rounded down instead of rounded up. `f"{x / 1000:.2g}"` works for 2250 which rounds it down to 2.2 but it doesn't work for 2350  which gets rounds up to 2.4. Do you know what might be the cause of that?

Comment: yes they already are acheiving that using ROUND_HALF_DOWN from the math module. The issue was with the precision width on where to decide to round teh remaining digits from.

Comment: @RonZhang the default rounding method for half is that you round up on odd and down on evens. This is the default implementation and a standard format. since the OP always wants to round down they have correctly sett the rounding rule of math modules get context as ROUND_HALF_DOWN to ensure it always rounds down.

Comment: This default method is known as bankers rounding and the rule is you round to the nearest even digit. So 2.5 will round to 2  as 2 is the nearest even number. 3.5 will round to 4 since 4 is the closest even number

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple algorithm that helps you round down numbers with trailing 50. I haven't tested it extensively, but it passes all your cases.

```
import math

def round100(x):
   return int(math.ceil((x-50.0)/100.0)) / 10.0

input = [2249, 2250, 2251, 2349, 2350, 2351]
for i in input:
   print(round100(i))
```